# Receiving push notifications from iCloud on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, watchkit, cloudkit

I have an app that supports both iOS and watchOS. They operate on data stored in iCloud. What I am trying to do is receive notifications on the Apple Watch when data changes on the iCloud server so I can update complications.

I'm trying to set up a subscription using `CKQuerySubscription` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in the extension delegate. I'm also calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` on `WKExtension`.

- The container and record type are correct, my predicate is `TRUEPREDICATE`
- I'm operating on the private database
- The subscription save process (i.e. `database.save(subscription)`) succeeds
- The remote notification registration process succeeds (`didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` is called)
- I am running on an actual device and have breakpoints confirming everything sets up fine and nothing comes up as a result
- The watch extension has remote notification background mode and push notification capabilities set up
- The data comes up fine through regular queries when I launch the actual app on the watch

The problem is:

- `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called

Is it actually possible to get push notifications from iCloud or should I just abandon this idea?

Comment: Have you made any progress on figuring this out? I am running into the same issue, and re-watched the WWDC 2019 video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/208/) about the topic to make sure I'm not missing anything, but no luck. I am trying with `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` like you, although that's not supposed to be required for silent content push notifications.

Comment: After this previous comment I got it working, but it seems inconsistent. And I can’t figure out how to give the CloudKit notifications the complication update priority.

Comment: On further investigation, it looks like the push notifications are received by the watchOS app when it is in the foreground. I am still testing to see whether they are ever received in the background (like on the next background refresh). I was hoping there would be a way to use PushKit and somehow have CloudKit send a notification with `PKPushType.complication`, but it seems it is not possible to use PushKit with CloudKit and only with your own server.

Comment: @gohnjanotis I came to the same conclusion, that it is only active when the app is in the foreground. For now, I am getting the data I display in the watch app using the CloudKit container but I'm also updating the complication from the phone app using WatchConnectivity.

Comment: Check ppix's answer in developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126286

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the following:
A silent push notification is indeed handled by watchOS, but only very rarely and pushes may be dropped. [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) say:

> The system treats background notifications as low priority: you can
> use them to refresh your app’s content, but the system doesn’t
> guarantee their delivery. In addition, the system may throttle the
> delivery of background notifications if the total number becomes
> excessive. The number of background notifications allowed by the
> system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than
> two or three per hour.

> When a device receives a background notification, the system may hold
> and delay the delivery of the notification, which can have the
> following side effects: When the system receives a new background
> notification, it discards the older notification and only holds the
> newest one.

So iCloud pushes are not really suited for updating a complication.

If one does not use iCloud but a separate server, one can use [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) to update complications. I find it strange that Apple did not implement this (yet?) for iCloud.
See also my question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68435996/1987726).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same scenario as @whistler.
Everything works and is in order for received remote notifications on watchOS, except for: `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

But I found out that by requesting authorisation for user notifications helped deliver them more often, still not delivering all of them but at least more frequently (and still only on the foreground it seems).

To request authorisation for user notifications simply:

```swift
try? await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert])
```

This doesn't seem to prompt the user with an alert on watchOS.